# Listener-specific timeout variables for event handler throttle or delay (debounce)?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, listener, throttling, debouncing

In order to eliminate some duplicative code, I need some generic functions that throttle and delay (debounce) event handling. This needs to be done in a way that allows these functions to be both added and removed as event listeners. My current approach relies on binding a specific event handling function (along with some parameters) to the generic throttled or delayed event handler function. The throttle and delay approach relies on global variables to store timeout ids. The downside of this approach is the potential for conflicts with the use of the global timeout variables if multiple event listeners are utilizing these generic throttle and delay functions..

Is there another way to implement these generic throttled / delayed event handler functions that eliminates the potential for conflicts in clearing and reassigning the global timeout variables when multiple event listeners are depending on the same generic throttle or delay function?

The snippet below illustrates the approach with a single global timeout variable for each of the throttled and delayed event handler functions. I would prefer to find a way to use a specific timeout variable for each underlying handler function (such as the `resizeHandler` and `mousemoveHandler` example functions below).

```js
// global object storing timeout ids for each type of handler
const timeouts = { delay: null, throttle: null };

// delays function call until at least "delay" ms have passed since last event
const delayedHandler = (...params) => {
  const [handler, delay, event] = params;
  clearTimeout(timeouts.delay);
  timeouts.delay = setTimeout(handler, delay, event);
};

// throttles function calls at an interval of at least "delay" ms
const throttledHandler = (...params) => {
  const timeoutHandler = (handler, event) => {
    timeouts.throttle = null;
    handler(event);
  };

  const [handler, delay, event] = params;
  if (!timeouts.throttle) {
    timeouts.throttle = setTimeout(timeoutHandler, delay, handler, event);
  }
};

// following illustrates add and remove of delayed / throttled handlers 
const resizeHandler = (event) => console.log(event.type);
const mousemoveHandler = (event) => console.log(event.type);
const delayedResizeHandler = delayedHandler.bind(window, resizeHandler, 167);
const throttledMousemoveHandler = throttledHandler.bind(window, mousemoveHandler, 66);
window.addEventListener('resize', delayedResizeHandler);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', throttledMousemoveHandler);
document.querySelector('#resize').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', delayedResizeHandler);
});
  
document.querySelector('#mousemove').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', throttledMousemoveHandler);
});
```

```html
<button id="resize" type="button">Remove resize handler</button>
<button id="mousemove" type="button">Remove mousemove handler</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out one approach by creating instances of the timeout variable and generic delay or throttle function when adding the event listener and then removing those instances when removing the listener (so no longer sharing timeout variables if multiple listeners added using the same generic delay or throttle function). Not sure this is the best approach since it relies on setting a data attribute for target elements (to facilitate listener removal) and relies on unique event type / handler function name combinations for non-element event targets such as `window` (otherwise, conflicting listeners will be overwritten for non-element targets).

```js
const db = {};
const decorators = {
  // delays event handler call until at least "delay" ms have passed since last event
  delay: (...params) => {
    const [i, eventtype, funcname, handler, delay, eventobj] = params;
    clearTimeout(db[i][eventtype][funcname].timeout);
    db[i][eventtype][funcname].timeout = setTimeout(handler, delay, eventobj);
  },

  // throttles function calls at an interval of at least "delay" ms
  throttle: (...params) => {
    const decorator = (i, eventtype, funcname, handler, eventobj) => {
      db[i][eventtype][funcname].timeout = null;
      handler(eventobj);
    };

    const [i, eventtype, funcname, handler, delay, eventobj] = params;
    if (!db[i][eventtype][funcname].timeout) {
      db[i][eventtype][funcname].timeout = setTimeout(
        decorator, delay, i, eventtype, funcname, handler, eventobj
      );
    }
  }
};

// add or remove event listeners
const eventify = (() => {
  const addListener = (elem, eventtype, handlerobj, decorator = null, delay = 0) => {
    const [[funcname, handler]] = Object.entries(handlerobj);
    let i = elem instanceof Element ? elem.dataset.eventify : 1;
    if (i === 1 && !(i in db)) {
      db[i] = {};
    }

    if (!i) {
      const dbkeys = Object.keys(db);
      i = dbkeys.length ? Math.max(...dbkeys.map((n) => Number(n))) + 1 : 2;
      elem.setAttribute('data-eventify', i);
      db[i] = {};
    }
    
    if (!(eventtype in db[i])) {
      db[i][eventtype] = {};
    }

    if (decorator) {
      db[i][eventtype][funcname] = {
        timeout: null,
        handleEvent: decorators[decorator].bind(elem, i, eventtype, funcname, handler, delay)
      };
    } else {
      db[i][eventtype][funcname] = { handleEvent: handler };
    }

    elem.addEventListener(eventtype, db[i][eventtype][funcname]);
  };

  const removeListener = (elem, eventtype, handlerobj) => {
    const i = elem instanceof Element ? elem.dataset.eventify : 1;
    const [funcname] = Object.keys(handlerobj);
    elem.removeEventListener(eventtype, db[i][eventtype][funcname]);
    delete db[i][eventtype][funcname];
  };

  return {
    addListener,
    removeListener
  };
})();

// usage
const resizeHandler = (event) => console.log(event.type);
const mousemoveHandler = (event) => console.log(event.type);
eventify.addListener(window, 'resize', { resizeHandler }, 'delay', 167);
eventify.addListener(window, 'mousemove', { mousemoveHandler }, 'throttle', 66);
document.querySelector('#resize').addEventListener('click', () => {
  eventify.removeListener(window, 'resize', { resizeHandler });
});
  
document.querySelector('#mousemove').addEventListener('click', () => {
  eventify.removeListener(window, 'mousemove', { mousemoveHandler });
});
```

```html
<button id="resize" type="button">Remove resize handler</button>
<button id="mousemove" type="button">Remove mousemove handler</button>
```